# Scrapy паук не доходит до конечной страницы

Tags: python, scrapy

Есть паук на Scrapy обходит половину страниц и останавливается до конечной не доходит в чём
может быть причина?

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "quotes"
start_urls = [
    'https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/elektronika/noutbuki-periferiya/kompyutery? 
      sort=popular&page=1',
]



def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.css('div.j-card-item'):
        yield {
            # 'link': res,
            'name': quote.css('span.goods-name::text').get(),
            'brend': quote.css('strong.brand-name::text').get(),
            'price': quote.css('ins.lower-price::text').get()
        }

    next_page = response.css('div.pageToInsert a::attr(href)').get()
    if next_page is not None:
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: павук которому не повезло

Comment: не понял а чем ему не повезло?